# When to use "avoir" or "être" in the "passé composé"

Tags: grammaire

I’ve heard that “avoir” is used with a transitive verb and “être” is used with an intransitive verb. But how about these?

> Je n'ai jamais conduit sur l'autoroute.
>   Je suis monté sur la tour Eiffel pour la première fois.

“Conduire” and “monter” can be both a transitive verb and an intransitive verb, can’t they?

This is not a duplicate. I want more correct and precise answer in some specific cases.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean in your need for a "more correct answer" However, This question being now marked duplicate, it seems just impossible to add a new answer. I suggest you act as advised : ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I’ve just done.