# When to use “avoir” or “être” in the “passé composé” (again)

Tags: grammaire, passé-composé, transitivité

I’ve heard that “avoir” is used with a transitive verb and “être” is used with an intransitive verb. But how about these?

> Je n'ai jamais conduit sur l'autoroute.
>   Je suis monté sur la tour Eiffel pour la première fois.

“Conduire” and “monter” can be both a transitive verb and an intransitive verb, but the first example has “avoir” and the second one has “être”. What’s the difference?

I once asked this, but it was marked as duplicate. And I was suggested to ask again.

Comment: The question [When to use “avoir” or “être” in the “passé composé](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8394/358) has already been answered. Your question is really about transitive & intransitive verbs. Check if it has not already been asked before you reformulate this one.  In your second sentence  *monter* is **intransitive** (it has no direct object). So your question is **not** about using *avoir* or *être* but could be why can *monter*  be sometimes transitive and at other times be intransitive. *Conduire* is **always transitive**.

Comment: @Laure : Ne vas pas si vite en besogne. Je crois que l'OP a bien considéré les autres pseudo-duplicates et qu'ils ne répondent pas à sa question précise qui, à mon opinion, tient à la compréhension quand les questions suggérées duplicates n'ont apporté que des *tips & tricks*. No disrespect meant.

Comment: @aCOSwt And none taken, all I'm doing is suggesting they modify the question,  "When to use “avoir” or “être” in the “passé composé”" is **not** what they want to know. Helping them to understand their problem so that they can write a clearer question. Rewriting exactly the same question as one that was closed instead of **modifying** the first one is to my mind not the best option.

Comment: @Laure : You are indeed correct however, the automated box showing the closure explicitely invites to open a **new** question.

Comment: @Laure As you say I need correct understanding about transitive & intransitive verbs. I would like to ask you about your comment “Conduire is always transitive.” Conduire there has no object or should I also modify the sentence? And I also want to say that if I understood transitive & intransitive verbs, my question couldn’t be solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use "avoir" or "être" in the "passé composé"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39957/when-to-use-avoir-or-%c3%aatre-in-the-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rules of thumb for auxiliary verbs (avoir/être) in passé composé?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/rules-of-thumb-for-auxiliary-verbs-avoir-%c3%aatre-in-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9)

Comment: @Yamacure Would you mind changing the title of your question into "How can I differentiate transitive and intransitive verbs" ? Which is what the accepted (and to my mind correct) answer is about?

Comment: @Laure  Thank you for your advice. I may need to know how to differentiate transitive and intransitive verbs to solve my question. And I want to know it too. But that’s all.

Comment: The accepted answer tells you how to differentiate transitive and intransitive verbs, if is not enough you can ask @aCOSwt to add something to their answer, but as it stands your question here which is asking "When to use “avoir” or “être” in the “passé composé” (again)" might again been closed since it was already asked and answered elsewhere. You really have to make it more clear that your question **is not** about how to chose between *être* and *avoir* but about transitive and intransitive verbs. It must have either have the words "transitive" and "intransitive" or the word "transitivity".

Comment: @Laure Due to my poor English, I don’t understand some of your sentences.  But I found that you suggested to me that I should make a different title to have better answers than ever. It’s so kind of you. Thank you. And it may not be proper to ask here, but does the accepted answer tell me how to differentiate transitive and intransitive verbs? I thought that it’s just about when to use avoir or être.

Comment: The answer you accepted tells you about how to differentiate transitive and intransitive verbs by reasoning. I think it is a good answer. If you do not have those in you native language it might indeed be difficult. But if you do not change the title the question might get closed again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

I understand that you need a more precise understanding and not the usual tips & tricks.
(No disrespect meant, tips & tricks are useful. But, they usually put forward a distinction *transitive* vs *intransitive* which, for being quite handy puts the entire thing in a shadow which obliterates understanding.)

---

The real difference to be made between verbs is the very first historically made by first grammars which had two categories of verbs : ACTIVE and PASSIVE.
This is the real drive to the understanding of the choice in auxiliaries.

As I already showed that somewhere else, grammars have since made other categories driven around TRANSITIVITY which more or less tries to cope with the ancient categories but leaves in a complete darkness (arbitrary decision) ACTIVE verbs used in a PASSIVE meaning and PASSIVE verbs used in an ACTIVE meaning.

This explains why decision grounded on transitivity is generally acceptable and handy for cookbooks (no disrespect meant) but leaves just many exceptions together with general incomprehension regarding the real trigger.

---

ACTIVE verbs as well as verbs used in a ACTIVE meaning need *avoir* as the auxiliary needed to construct the composed tenses.
PASSIVE verbs as well as verbs used in PASSIVE meaning need *être* as the auxiliary needed to construct the composed tenses.

---

Period.

---

Coming to your particular examples :

- *Je n'**ai** jamais conduit sur l'autoroute.* You mean the process of driving, the action of driving, the event => ACTIVE meaning => *avoir*
- *Je **suis** monté sur la tour Eiffel* You mean the fact you have been on the top. A status of yourself, not the action of climbing. => PASSIVE meaning -=> *être*

Note that with this *monter*, you could well have said :

- *J'**ai** monté l'escalier de la tour Eiffel* Insisting on the process of climbing. ACTIVE meaning => avoir.

---

On a side note, It should be acknowledged that while being still held as a *barbarism*, some contemporary authors prefer *Il a mouru* to the supposedly correct *Il est mort* when they speak about the event and not the status.

On an other historical side note, when contemporary grammarians would boo some *J'ai allé* everybody applaused when troubadours singing *la chanson de Roland* were saying *Ils n'orent mie iiii liues alés* que l'on pourrait traduire mot à mot précisément par *ils n'**ont** pas allé quatre lieues*.(1)

Eh oui! L'invention du passé composé date de cette époque avec un choix d'auxiliaire exclusivement fondé sur l'aspectuel.

---

<sup>1 : On préférerait aujourd'hui traduire par *"Ils n'ont pas **fait** quatre lieues*</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apart from grammatical definitions, a passive-like verb needs être, right? I would like to ask you some more questions. First, conduire there is a transitive verb? (I don’t think so.) Second, are really all the transitive verbs need avoir?

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord du tout avec votre « passif » : un présent à la voix passive ? Qu'est-ce que vous faites du passé composé « je suis monté » ? Il n'est question que de ce temps ici. https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/search?verb=monter (TLFi) S'élever
a) pour se trouver plus haut. Synon. grimper. Monter sur/à un arbre,

Comment: @Yamacure : I tried to explain the real thing governing the choice of auxiliaries. I wanted to show you something else than what you had already read (as you had asked). Please, don't want me to come back here to the transitive stuff that is already written elsewhere.

Comment: @LPH : Étant dit que j'ai traité le cas *Je suis monté* dans le corps de ma contribution. Je comprends que vous puissiez ne pas être d'accord dans la mesure où je présente une autre compréhension des choses que la traditionnelle. Après après... là où **vous vous** trompez sûrement: Le passé-composé n'a **jamais** été **que** une question de temps.

Comment: @aCOSwt Qu'est-ce que vous faite d'un possible complément d'agent ? « Cette pièce est montée sur un cadre. » comporte une forme passive. Mais quelle est l'acception de monter dans votre cas ? Je n'en vois aucune. J'ai l'impression que vous chamboulez les notions acquises et je n'en vois pas très bien la motivation.

Comment: @LPH : Je ne chamboule rien du tout. Car d'autres l'ont fait et bien avant moi. Oui! Ce que je présente (trop rapidement) est différent de ce que l'on fait traditionnellement apprendre par cœur  (car fondé sur une catégorisation ausi floue qu'arbitraire) et qui déroute tant les locuteurs non natifs. J'essaye autre chose donc, orienté pour la compréhension de ceux qui ne savent pas encore. C'est encore à dire pas de vous qui... savez déjà tout. (ou avez déjà tout appris... autrement)

Comment: @aCOSwt Je vois… mais ne croyez-vous pas que cela relève du domaine du spécialiste, ou d'un projet de (r)établir certaines normes, ce qui demanderait d'abord beaucoup de concertation, et que dans le cadre du FSE, sur lequel on prône, et pas qu'illégitimement, que l'on devrait épargner à l'apprenant les affres de la théorie avancée, il serait plus sage de s'en tenir à la norme qui est reconnue pour l'instant ?

Comment: @LPH : S'en tenir à la norme ? Mais... il existe d'autres très bonnes contributions sur ce sujet qui s'en tiennent à cette norme. Elles ont été signalées à l'OP qui a affirmé que ce n'était pas cela qu'il cherchait. J'ai donc cherché autre chose.

Comment: @aCOSwt Thank you. I will try your way to judge. If I find a verb that can’t be understood in your way, I’ll ask again.

Comment: @Yamacure : You are welcome. Anyway, that is the only way to **understand** instead of learning by heart. Grammar rules **are** understandable. Because there is always some logic grounding them. When no logics support some grammar rule... this one always fades away... quickly!

Comment: Est-ce que tu crois que je pourrais renommer la question. Le PO a reconnu que son problème était de ne pas comprendre la transitivité mais n'a pas compris l'intérêt de renommer la question. Elle va être fermée, mais est-ce grave ? Un jour quelqu'un posera la question sur la transitivité, sera-t-il redirigé ici ?

Comment: @Laure : D'abord merci beaucoup pour le bounty. Je suis confus. Je ne vois pas vraiment la nécessité de faire quoi que ce soit sur ce sujet (fermer / retitrer) dans la mesure où l'OP a accepté une réponse cela signifie à mes yeux que tout *fit* comme il faut.

Comment: @Laure : Le problème de la transitivité est un binz beaucoup plus général que j'avais tenté de boucler ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32316/lemploi-absolu-dun-verbe-et-le-verbe-intransitif-perspectives mais... voulant montrer à quel point c'était le boxif, j'ai fait de ma partie historique un boxif pas possible. Il faudra que j'y revienne un jour.

Comment: J'avais raté cette réponse (époque où j'ai commencé à délaissé le site pour incompatibilité... je fais un nouvel essai actuellement, à voir...), je pense que c'est bien de secouer les idées inculquées à coup de par cœur à l'époque par des enseignants pleins de bonne volonté mais pas toujours bien armés. J'ai parcouru le tag *transivity* sur linguisitics mais rien trouvé de satisfaisant, parce que le phénomène ne se limite pas au français.

Answer (score 3):

Je réalise que mon autre réponse ici pose quelques interrogations et que la distinction basée sur la transitivité reste tenace.
Plutôt que de la reprendre (je ne ferais alors rien de mieux que recopier les réponses apportées dans d'autres questions, je vais tenter de montrer comment la transitivité a pu être bricolée en tant que critère de choix)

---

**LE LATIN CLASSIQUE**
*Être* est le seul auxiliaire permettant la formation des temps composés. Et le participe passé exprime quasi-exclusivement l'**état du sujet**. *Natus sum*

**LE GALLO-ROMAN**
C'est le véritable inventeur de "notre" *passé composé*.
En tant qu'il va utiliser *avoir* en tant qu'auxiliaire lorsqu'il s'agira de porter l'accent sur la **perfectivité de l'action**. *Habeo bibendum*! Hips! Pardon!

Pour de nombreux verbes, les deux auxiliaires sont donc possibles, pour prendre l'exemple d'*aller* (qui ne se conjugue plus aujourd'hui qu'avec l'auxiliaire être) on pouvait tout autant dire :

***Alez*** en **est** un verger suz l'umbre (Roland) Pour indiquer la position instantanée du sujet (dans le verger), **l'état du sujet résultant de l'action** d'aller

que :

*Ils n'**orent** mie iiii liues **alé*** Qu'on traduirait aujourd'hui par *Ils n'eurent pas **fait** quatre lieues* pour signifier non plus l'état du sujet au bout du chemin mais sa progression sur le chemin. L'**action du sujet**.

**DE LA TRANSITIVITE**
Les verbes ne sont pas à l'époque de Roland catégorisés selon des critères de transitivité.
Cette classification viendra (après de nombreux errements, interprétations différentes et décisions arbitraires) bien plus tard.

Dans cette conception *moderne* (que beaucoup appellent à faire exploser) on va analyser la phrase ci-dessus autrement :

Le participe passé ***alé*** ne s'applique pas au **sujet** mais à l'**objet**. Ce n'est plus le sujet qui est *alé* mais bien plus plutôt les quatre lieues.

D'où vient, pour utiliser l'auxiliaire *avoir* la nécessité de pouvoir reporter le participe passé sur un objet et de la la nécessaire *transitivité*.

*J'ai monté les escaliers*. Oui! Car ce sont les escaliers qui sont montés.

*Je suis monté en haut de la tour*. Oui aussi! Car c'est le sujet (Je) qui monte.

Cette liberté de choix de l'auxiliaire n'existe plus guère aujourd'hui que pour un nombre limité de verbes qui sont principalement des verbes de mouvement.

---

Voilà comment il est possible de bricoler un critère de choix sur la base d'une connaissance (par cœur) de la transitivité (arbitraire)

Mais j'en remets une couche : La véritable décision est à comprendre dans mon autre contribution qui offre aussi le mérite de **comprendre** pourquoi *être, dormir, pleurer...* sont conjugués avec l'auxiliaire avoir, ce que la transitivité ne permettra jamais.

Comment: [The Passive and the Notion of Transitivity](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-01020510/file/The_passive_and_the_notion_of_transitivity_pdf_-_copie.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The rule giving which verb is proper is [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8394/17649).

You say that « monter » is both transitive and intransitive; it's not quite so. You are dealing here with  two acceptations for a given form; there is a strong similarity between the two but that's all; thus, the form "monter" embodies  not just one verb but two. The definitions can be checked in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monter); they are and repeated below for convenience (highlighted in yellow, user **LPH** bold type).

> I. Emploi intrans.
>   A. [Le suj. désigne un être vivant]
>   3. **S'élever**
>   b) **pour être à un niveau où l'on est plus ou mieux en vue.**
>   Monter sur le billard, sur une table d'opération; monter sur l'échafaud, sur un piédestal, sur les planches, sur le théâtre, sur le trône; monter au pinacle, à la tribune.

As the rule referred to at the beginning shows (verb indicating motion that is intransitive and therefore an exception and subject to the "house" rule (être)) you use "être".

- Je **suis monté** sur la Tour Eiffel pour la première fois.

> II. Emploi trans.
>   A. [Monter implique une notion d'élévation]
>   1. **Parcourir en s'élevant, grimper, faire l'escalade de**.
>    Monter les marches, les degrés d'un escalier; monter un escalier, deux étages, une côte, une pente, une rampe; monter trois cordes à la force du poignet.
>
> - J'ai monté le Saint-Gothard à une heure du matin, par une lune sublime;

- As there is no exceptional case in the exemple below, you use "avoir" (according to the rule).
- J'**ai monté** les escaliers de la Tour Eiffel quatre à quatre… au début !

The reasoning when dealing with "conduire" and other verbs is the same.

In the case of "conduire" in your example you can see it is not  reciprocal, not reflexive and not in the "house". Therefore you have to use "avoir" whether the form is that of a transitive verb or not : "j'ai conduit *le cheval* à l'abattoir." (transitive), "J'ai conduit *sur une route mouillée*." ("emploi absolu";  not stated but possible: "ma voiture", "une voiture", "un camion", etc). Here, you should have checked in a good dictionary (TLFi) and you would have found that "conduire" in your example is never intransitive but that it is used in "emploi absolu" (which makes it look as if it were intransitive); however that changes nothing, as it is not in the "house". If you are talking of "conduire" in its reflexive sense, then it is different: "Je me **suis conduit** plutôt mal." (according to the rule).

---

So as to make the rule possibly simpler and more complete I'll give it the following form.

The verb "avoir" is used with all  transitive verbs and all intransitive verbs except for a small list of intransitive verbs;

That list comprises intransitive the verbs that connote the idea of basic motion, for a part of them.

**A**

entrer
arriver
venir
accourir
monter
descendre
passer
retourner
sortir
partir
aller
tomber

**B**

advenir, devenir, intervenir, obvenir, survenir
ressortir
apparaitre
décéder
échoir
naitre
mourir
rester

There are two categories to keep in mind when applying that rule.

1/ The verbs connoting motion must be distinguished from more complex intransitive verbs connoting motion, as those describe a complex type of motion and as the usual verb "avoir" is used for them.

chanceler, chuter, danser, déambuler, déraper,pivoter, provenir, slalomer, skier, tituber, tourbillonner, tournailler, tournicoter, tournoyer, sauter, tressauter, trépigner, 
vaciller, valdinguer, valser

2/ A second category of verbs to watch, is that of a short list of verbs that have the same form as verbs in « **A** » but which are transitive and have a differnt meaning; the auxiliary for the transitive form must be "avoir". Here is their list.

passer, sortir, rentrer, monter, descendre, retourner

- Elle est passé à l'étage au-dessus. ■ Il a passé *son temps* à la télévision.
- Le chat est sorti. ■ Elle a sorti *une bouteille* du réfrigérateur.
- Ils sont rentré à lécole hier. ■ La dame a rentré *son linge* avant la pluie.
- Il est monté dans sa chambre à minuit. ■ Il avait monté *deux étages* seulement pour aller se coucher.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Thanks to you, now I know there are verbs that need both “avoir” and “être” depending on the context. I would like to ask you about “conduire”. Do you think “conduire” in my sentence is transitive? I think the “conduire” has no object, so I think it’s intransitive and this is the definition of “intransitive”.

Comment: @Yamacure It's a matter of how you look at it; some people like to see only one word for a given form, but I tend to consider that for every new meaning of a form we are dealing with a new word. You can still hold the other point of view, but don't  forget the meanings are different even if there is a relation between the two. Yes,it's transitiveit, and as a matter of fact it is always transitive; as I explain in the answer, it's a little tricky: the use in your sentence (1/2)

Comment: @Yamacure  is the "**emploi absolu**" and that signifies that the object that often is used with the verb is missing. The lack of an object is however the caracteristic of intransitive verbs, wherefrom the difficulty. When having problems with words always try first to determine their grammatical nature from a dictionary; it might be a bit difficult at the beginning but before too long you'll get the hang of it, will understand better and get much useful information. (2/2)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong. There is only a short list of non-pronominal verbs which are ever conjugated with *être* (see the potential duplicate). It is only for those that the transitive/intransitive test must be done.

Comment: Je vais tenter une réponse mais, bien que *handy* et communément repris, ce n'est pas le test de transitivité qu'il convient de faire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’d like to ask you if there’s a verb that is conjugated with both être and avoir depending on its meaning?

Comment: @aCOSwt Je la vois. Intéressante mais je ne suis pas sûr que les nuances qu'elle apporte conviennent au niveau de maîtrise de l'OP.

Comment: @Yamacure none that I can think of currently.

Comment: Tu as très probablement (mais bien malheureusement) raison. Et pourtant... Cette nuance a été maîtrisée et comprise par tout le monde dès le moyen âge. C'est tout l'amphigouri de la reclassification arbitraire des verbes basée sur la transitivité qui a phoutu le brin et ne permet plus de comprendre. On ne peut plus... qu'apprendre par cœur. C'est plus simple, plus immédiat mais, je le déplore.